# Update specific columns Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have an edit profile section and i want  the user to be able to update everything except the password. I ve tried removing the password lines on my controller but it does not update it just shows the same data as before .Any help is appreciated .

This is my edit controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;


class UserController extends Controller
{
  public function __construct()
  {
      $this->middleware('auth');
  }

  public function edit(User $user)
  {
      $user = Auth::user();
      return view('users.edit', compact('user'));
  }

  public function update(Request $request,User $user)
  {


        $this->validate($request, [
            'org_name' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users,org_name,'.$user->id,
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users,email,'.$user->id,
            'username' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users,username,'.$user->id,
            'password' => 'required|string|min:8',
            'country' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'org_type' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'depart' => 'required|string|max:255',
      ]);

        $user->org_name = $request->get('org_name');
        $user->email = $request->get('email');
        $user->username = $request->get('username');
        $user->password = bcrypt($request->get('password'));
        $user->country = $request->get('country');
        $user->org_type = $request->get('org_type');
        $user->depart = $request->get('depart');
        $user->save();

        return back();
    }
}
```

and this is a section of the form

```
  <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

      <div class="col-md-6">
          <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" >

          @error('password')
              <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                  <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
              </span>
          @enderror
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

      <div class="col-md-6">
          <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="country" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Country') }}</label>

      <div class="col-md-6">
          <input id="country" type="text" class="form-control" name="country" value="{{$user->country}}">

          @error('country')
              <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                  <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
              </span>
          @enderror
      </div>
  </div>
```

thanks in advance~

Comment: Did you also remove the validation for password? `'password' => 'required|string|min:8',`

Comment: What debugging have you done? Is `$user` getting passed to the method properly? Does the request pass validation? Is `$fillable` set on your model? Why not just use `$user->update($request->all())`? And if they should update "everything except the password" why is there a line updating the password?

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes

Comment: Then WHY is it still in the code that you show us ???

Comment: @RiggsFolly mate thats my original code, at the start of my sentence i said , i tried removing those 2 lines and the password fields in my view.it didnt work , so i reverted back

Comment: Well it has confused me, and TWO other who wrote answer based on the code they can see. What point is there on validating a password that eiter is not there or you dont actually want to write to the database

Comment: sorry i just had to refresh the serve.... now it works just by removing the 2 password lines, Thanks for the help.

Comment: You mean the answer I gave that proved to be exactly correct?

Comment: @RiggsFolly i am speechless . Thanks for the help man so helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is, if you send no Password, you will be return back to the view.

You Need to delete these lines on your controller:

```
$user->password = bcrypt($request->get('password'));
```

And delete:

```
'password' => 'required|string|min:8',
```

from the `$this->validate($request,`

Then update your view so it doesn´t send the Password:

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

  <div class="col-md-6">
      <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" >

      @error('password')
          <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
              <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
          </span>
      @enderror
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

  <div class="col-md-6">
      <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
  </div>
</div>
```

This will work.

Comment: Also delete this line on the Controller: $user->password = bcrypt($request->get('password'));

Comment: you want me to delete the two lines in the controller and the form blocks in the view that show the password? I ve already said i tried that, if not can you explain ?

Comment: I am actually doing the same thing on one of my Projects. I deleted those lines, and added some additional ones i needed to the view and i had no issues. Hmm… You are not getting an error message? correct?

Comment: Did you delete this line on the Controller too? "'password' => 'required|string|min:8',"

Comment: I see on other commets that you did. Please post your updated Code. The Problem seams to be somewhere else.

Comment: sorry i just had to refresh the serve.... now it works just by removing the 2 password lines, Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad to here it works :)

Comment: I rest my case your honor

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 public function update(Request $request)
  {
    $userId = auth()->user()->id;


    $this->validate($request, [
        'org_name' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users,org_name,'.$user->id,
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users,email,'.$user->id,
        'username' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users,username,'.$user->id,
        'country' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'org_type' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'depart' => 'required|string|max:255',
      ]);
             $user = User::find($userId);
             $user->org_name = $request->get('org_name');
             $user->email = $request->get('email');
             $user->username = $request->get('username');
             $user->country = $request->get('country');
             $user->org_type = $request->get('org_type');
             $user->depart = $request->get('depart');
             $user->save();

            return back();

        }
  }
```

Comment: sorry i just had to refresh the serve.... now it works just by removing the 2 password lines, Thanks for the help.

Comment: Oh nice. Could you please share the working version of the code? May be useful to someone else.

Comment: you need to remove the two password lines on the controller and on the view aswell.I just had to refresh my server with php artisan for it to work .